# Why didnt the view update the data from the SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework

So im currently facing a problem is that, im trying to update the data through the Stored Procedure. The data is updated, so as the view.

```
db.sp_Update_Book(MaNXB, MaTG, Tensach, Linhvuc, Gia, Vitri, Dangduocmuon, \nSoluongsachmat, Tongsoluong);
db.SaveChanges();
LoadData();
```

Here is the LoadData function. Its load the data from SQL to my datagridview

```
dgvQLSach.DataSource = db.Book_Info.ToList();
```

But when debugging its show the old data one, not the updated one.
Book_Info is a View from Model SACH

```
create view Book_Info as
SELECT TENSACH, LINHVUC, GIA, VITRI, DANGDUOCMUON, SOLUONGSACHBIMAT, TONGSOLUONG
FROM dbo.SACH
```

Edit: Miraclely, if i use db.SACH.ToList(), the data will be update like norrmal

Comment: Could you attach the `sp_Update_Book` block

Comment: i have tried to attach the `sp_Update_Block` but i got error because the return of the procedure is integer, not a table